# Function declaration inside loop

Tags: c++, c++14

I would like to know what happens when we declare a function inside a loop that runs for say, x times. For example,

```
int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        void my_func(){
            cout<<"Hello! Brother"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing will happen. This is not allowed in C++...

Comment: Yeah.. got it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't possible with normal functions.
However you can use lambdas to achieve the desired result instead:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // Create local lambda and call it afterwards.
        auto myfunc = []() {
            cout << "Hello! Brother" << endl;
        };
        myfunc();
        // alternatively, call lambda in situ
        // []() { cout << "Hello! Brother" << endl; }();
    }
}
```